# SQL - Nested select and Pivot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I Have this table :

```
create table #tmpState
(   sheet_id int, -- person sheet id
    qnumber int, -- Question number
    lsn_id int, -- lesson Id
    qstate nvarchar(1) -- 'T' ,  'F' , 'W'
)
```

I want to calculate this formula :

```
(((res.T - (res.F*(@FactorA/@FactorB)))*100)/count(res.lsn_id)) as lsnpercent


-- count(res.lsn_id) : count number of Question per lesson
```

now i write this select query :

```
select  * ,
   (((res.T - (res.F*(@FactorA/@FactorB)))*100)/count(res.lsn_id)) as lsnpercent
from (select * 
     from
     (select lsn_id , qstate from #tmpState ) as s
     pivot 
     (
         count(qstate)
         for [qstate] in (T,F,W)
     ) as pvt
     ) as res
```

the `#tmpState` table fill :

[image: <code>#tmpState</code> table :]

when i run this Query :

```
select * 
 from
 (select lsn_id , qstate from #tmpState ) as s
 pivot 
 (
     count(qstate)
     for [qstate] in (T,F,W)
 ) as pvt
```

result is :

[image]

**Problem :**
I want to add Column to second table that calculate 
this formula :

```
((res.T - (res.F*(@FactorA/@FactorB)))*100)/count(res.lsn_id))
```

like this:

[image]

**when i run this query :**

```
select  * ,
   (((res.T - (res.F*(@FactorA/@FactorB)))*100)/count(res.lsn_id)) as lsnpercent
from (select * 
     from
     (select lsn_id , qstate from #tmpState ) as s
     pivot 
     (
         count(qstate)
         for [qstate] in (T,F,W)
     ) as pvt
     ) as res
```

**Message Error :**

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 122 Column 'res.lsn_id' is invalid
>   in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) you have to use

```
select  pvt.[lsn_id], pvt.[T], pvt.[F], pvt.[W]
        ,[lsnpercent] = ((pvt.[T] - (pvt.[F] * (@FactorA/@FactorB))) * 100)/count(*) over()
from (select [lsn_id], [qstate] from #tmpState) as s
pivot (count(s.[qstate]) for s.[qstate] in ([T], [F], [W])) as pvt
```

Comment: thanks , your code is correct , and error on `count(*) over()` , but no problem, I revise my code and find i can replace `count(*) over()` with `pvt.[T]+ pvt.[F]+ pvt.[W]` . now it's execute with no error.

Answer (score 1):

You can change formula to this:

```
((res.T - (res.F*(@FactorA/@FactorB)))*100)/count(*) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)))
```

Every row has its own `lsn_id` so you can count all rows with OVER clause.